# Use of ctypes module

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to program VIX API of VMware. It´s a dll wrote with C functions...

I want program in python calling this functions using ctypes and I don´t understand the documentation of ctypes in python web page...

Can someone give some samples with how to do this????

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been meaning to do something like this for a while.  I downloaded the VIX API kit, and extracted the vix.h file, containing all of the VIX API function prototypes.  I then wrote a short pyparsing parser to extract the typedefs and function declarations, and convert them to ctypes definitions.  With these definitions, you'll be able to invoke the VIX methods from the VIX dll (the lib's are not needed, only the dll is used by ctypes).

Extract this code to a suitably-named Python module (vixlib.py, for instance), and then import this module into any Python script to use VIX:

```
from ctypes import *
# if on Windows, may need to change following to use WinDLL instead of CDLL
vix = CDLL('vix.dll')

# user defined types
VixHandle = c_int
VixHandleType = c_int
VixError = c_uint64
VixPropertyType = c_int
VixPropertyID = c_int
VixEventType = c_int
VixHostOptions = c_int
VixServiceProvider = c_int
VixFindItemType = c_int
VixVMOpenOptions = c_int
VixPumpEventsOptions = c_int
VixVMPowerOpOptions = c_int
VixVMDeleteOptions = c_int
VixPowerState = c_int
VixToolsState = c_int
VixRunProgramOptions = c_int
VixRemoveSnapshotOptions = c_int
VixCreateSnapshotOptions = c_int
VixMsgSharedFolderOptions = c_int
VixCloneType = c_int
VixEventProc = CFUNCTYPE(VixHandle,
    VixEventType,
    VixHandle,
    c_void_p)

# constant definitions
VIX_INVALID_HANDLE = 0
VIX_HANDLETYPE_NONE = 0
VIX_HANDLETYPE_HOST = 2
VIX_HANDLETYPE_VM = 3
VIX_HANDLETYPE_NETWORK = 5
VIX_HANDLETYPE_JOB = 6
VIX_HANDLETYPE_SNAPSHOT = 7
VIX_HANDLETYPE_PROPERTY_LIST = 9
VIX_HANDLETYPE_METADATA_CONTAINER = 11
VIX_OK = 0
VIX_E_FAIL = 1
VIX_E_OUT_OF_MEMORY = 2
VIX_E_INVALID_ARG = 3
VIX_E_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 4
VIX_E_OBJECT_IS_BUSY = 5
VIX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED = 6
VIX_E_FILE_ERROR = 7
VIX_E_DISK_FULL = 8
VIX_E_INCORRECT_FILE_TYPE = 9
VIX_E_CANCELLED = 10
VIX_E_FILE_READ_ONLY = 11
VIX_E_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS = 12
VIX_E_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR = 13
VIX_E_REQUIRES_LARGE_FILES = 14
VIX_E_FILE_ALREADY_LOCKED = 15
VIX_E_VMDB = 16
VIX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_REMOTE_OBJECT = 20
VIX_E_FILE_TOO_BIG = 21
VIX_E_FILE_NAME_INVALID = 22
VIX_E_ALREADY_EXISTS = 23
VIX_E_BUFFER_TOOSMALL = 24
VIX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND = 25
VIX_E_HOST_NOT_CONNECTED = 26
VIX_E_INVALID_UTF8_STRING = 27
VIX_E_OPERATION_ALREADY_IN_PROGRESS = 31
VIX_E_UNFINISHED_JOB = 29
VIX_E_NEED_KEY = 30
VIX_E_LICENSE = 32
VIX_E_VM_HOST_DISCONNECTED = 34
VIX_E_AUTHENTICATION_FAIL = 35
VIX_E_HOST_CONNECTION_LOST = 36
VIX_E_DUPLICATE_NAME = 41
VIX_E_INVALID_HANDLE = 1000
VIX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_HANDLE_TYPE = 1001
VIX_E_TOO_MANY_HANDLES = 1002
VIX_E_NOT_FOUND = 2000
VIX_E_TYPE_MISMATCH = 2001
VIX_E_INVALID_XML = 2002
VIX_E_TIMEOUT_WAITING_FOR_TOOLS = 3000
VIX_E_UNRECOGNIZED_COMMAND = 3001
VIX_E_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_GUEST = 3003
VIX_E_PROGRAM_NOT_STARTED = 3004
VIX_E_CANNOT_START_READ_ONLY_VM = 3005
VIX_E_VM_NOT_RUNNING = 3006
VIX_E_VM_IS_RUNNING = 3007
VIX_E_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_VM = 3008
VIX_E_POWEROP_SCRIPTS_NOT_AVAILABLE = 3009
VIX_E_NO_GUEST_OS_INSTALLED = 3010
VIX_E_VM_INSUFFICIENT_HOST_MEMORY = 3011
VIX_E_SUSPEND_ERROR = 3012
VIX_E_VM_NOT_ENOUGH_CPUS = 3013
VIX_E_HOST_USER_PERMISSIONS = 3014
VIX_E_GUEST_USER_PERMISSIONS = 3015
VIX_E_TOOLS_NOT_RUNNING = 3016
VIX_E_GUEST_OPERATIONS_PROHIBITED = 3017
VIX_E_ANON_GUEST_OPERATIONS_PROHIBITED = 3018
VIX_E_ROOT_GUEST_OPERATIONS_PROHIBITED = 3019
VIX_E_MISSING_ANON_GUEST_ACCOUNT = 3023
VIX_E_CANNOT_AUTHENTICATE_WITH_GUEST = 3024
VIX_E_UNRECOGNIZED_COMMAND_IN_GUEST = 3025
VIX_E_CONSOLE_GUEST_OPERATIONS_PROHIBITED = 3026
VIX_E_MUST_BE_CONSOLE_USER = 3027
VIX_E_VMX_MSG_DIALOG_AND_NO_UI = 3028
VIX_E_NOT_ALLOWED_DURING_VM_RECORDING = 3029
VIX_E_NOT_ALLOWED_DURING_VM_REPLAY = 3030
VIX_E_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED_FOR_LOGIN_TYPE = 3031
VIX_E_LOGIN_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED = 3032
VIX_E_EMPTY_PASSWORD_NOT_ALLOWED_IN_GUEST = 3033
VIX_E_INTERACTIVE_SESSION_NOT_PRESENT = 3034
VIX_E_INTERACTIVE_SESSION_USER_MISMATCH = 3035
VIX_E_UNABLE_TO_REPLAY_VM = 3039
VIX_E_CANNOT_POWER_ON_VM = 3041
VIX_E_NO_DISPLAY_SERVER = 3043
VIX_E_VM_NOT_RECORDING = 3044
VIX_E_VM_NOT_REPLAYING = 3045
VIX_E_VM_NOT_FOUND = 4000
VIX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_VM_VERSION = 4001
VIX_E_CANNOT_READ_VM_CONFIG = 4002
VIX_E_TEMPLATE_VM = 4003
VIX_E_VM_ALREADY_LOADED = 4004
VIX_E_VM_ALREADY_UP_TO_DATE = 4006
VIX_E_VM_UNSUPPORTED_GUEST = 4011
VIX_E_UNRECOGNIZED_PROPERTY = 6000
VIX_E_INVALID_PROPERTY_VALUE = 6001
VIX_E_READ_ONLY_PROPERTY = 6002
VIX_E_MISSING_REQUIRED_PROPERTY = 6003
VIX_E_INVALID_SERIALIZED_DATA = 6004
VIX_E_PROPERTY_TYPE_MISMATCH = 6005
VIX_E_BAD_VM_INDEX = 8000
VIX_E_INVALID_MESSAGE_HEADER = 10000
VIX_E_INVALID_MESSAGE_BODY = 10001
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_INVAL = 13000
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_DUMPER = 13001
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_DISKLIB = 13002
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_NOTFOUND = 13003
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_EXISTS = 13004
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_VERSION = 13005
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_NOPERM = 13006
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_CONFIG = 13007
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_NOCHANGE = 13008
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_CHECKPOINT = 13009
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_LOCKED = 13010
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_INCONSISTENT = 13011
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_NAMETOOLONG = 13012
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_VIXFILE = 13013
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_DISKLOCKED = 13014
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_DUPLICATEDDISK = 13015
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_INDEPENDENTDISK = 13016
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_NONUNIQUE_NAME = 13017
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_MEMORY_ON_INDEPENDENT_DISK = 13018
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_MAXSNAPSHOTS = 13019
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_MIN_FREE_SPACE = 13020
VIX_E_SNAPSHOT_HIERARCHY_TOODEEP = 13021
VIX_E_HOST_DISK_INVALID_VALUE = 14003
VIX_E_HOST_DISK_SECTORSIZE = 14004
VIX_E_HOST_FILE_ERROR_EOF = 14005
VIX_E_HOST_NETBLKDEV_HANDSHAKE = 14006
VIX_E_HOST_SOCKET_CREATION_ERROR = 14007
VIX_E_HOST_SERVER_NOT_FOUND = 14008
VIX_E_HOST_NETWORK_CONN_REFUSED = 14009
VIX_E_HOST_TCP_SOCKET_ERROR = 14010
VIX_E_HOST_TCP_CONN_LOST = 14011
VIX_E_HOST_NBD_HASHFILE_VOLUME = 14012
VIX_E_HOST_NBD_HASHFILE_INIT = 14013
VIX_E_DISK_INVAL = 16000
VIX_E_DISK_NOINIT = 16001
VIX_E_DISK_NOIO = 16002
VIX_E_DISK_PARTIALCHAIN = 16003
VIX_E_DISK_NEEDSREPAIR = 16006
VIX_E_DISK_OUTOFRANGE = 16007
VIX_E_DISK_CID_MISMATCH = 16008
VIX_E_DISK_CANTSHRINK = 16009
VIX_E_DISK_PARTMISMATCH = 16010
VIX_E_DISK_UNSUPPORTEDDISKVERSION = 16011
VIX_E_DISK_OPENPARENT = 16012
VIX_E_DISK_NOTSUPPORTED = 16013
VIX_E_DISK_NEEDKEY = 16014
VIX_E_DISK_NOKEYOVERRIDE = 16015
VIX_E_DISK_NOTENCRYPTED = 16016
VIX_E_DISK_NOKEY = 16017
VIX_E_DISK_INVALIDPARTITIONTABLE = 16018
VIX_E_DISK_NOTNORMAL = 16019
VIX_E_DISK_NOTENCDESC = 16020
VIX_E_DISK_NEEDVMFS = 16022
VIX_E_DISK_RAWTOOBIG = 16024
VIX_E_DISK_TOOMANYOPENFILES = 16027
VIX_E_DISK_TOOMANYREDO = 16028
VIX_E_DISK_RAWTOOSMALL = 16029
VIX_E_DISK_INVALIDCHAIN = 16030
VIX_E_DISK_KEY_NOTFOUND = 16052
VIX_E_DISK_SUBSYSTEM_INIT_FAIL = 16053
VIX_E_DISK_INVALID_CONNECTION = 16054
VIX_E_DISK_ENCODING = 16061
VIX_E_DISK_CANTREPAIR = 16062
VIX_E_DISK_INVALIDDISK = 16063
VIX_E_DISK_NOLICENSE = 16064
VIX_E_DISK_NODEVICE = 16065
VIX_E_DISK_UNSUPPORTEDDEVICE = 16066
VIX_E_CRYPTO_UNKNOWN_ALGORITHM = 17000
VIX_E_CRYPTO_BAD_BUFFER_SIZE = 17001
VIX_E_CRYPTO_INVALID_OPERATION = 17002
VIX_E_CRYPTO_RANDOM_DEVICE = 17003
VIX_E_CRYPTO_NEED_PASSWORD = 17004
VIX_E_CRYPTO_BAD_PASSWORD = 17005
VIX_E_CRYPTO_NOT_IN_DICTIONARY = 17006
VIX_E_CRYPTO_NO_CRYPTO = 17007
VIX_E_CRYPTO_ERROR = 17008
VIX_E_CRYPTO_BAD_FORMAT = 17009
VIX_E_CRYPTO_LOCKED = 17010
VIX_E_CRYPTO_EMPTY = 17011
VIX_E_CRYPTO_KEYSAFE_LOCATOR = 17012
VIX_E_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_HOST = 18000
VIX_E_NOT_FOR_REMOTE_HOST = 18001
VIX_E_INVALID_HOSTNAME_SPECIFICATION = 18002
VIX_E_SCREEN_CAPTURE_ERROR = 19000
VIX_E_SCREEN_CAPTURE_BAD_FORMAT = 19001
VIX_E_SCREEN_CAPTURE_COMPRESSION_FAIL = 19002
VIX_E_SCREEN_CAPTURE_LARGE_DATA = 19003
VIX_E_GUEST_VOLUMES_NOT_FROZEN = 20000
VIX_E_NOT_A_FILE = 20001
VIX_E_NOT_A_DIRECTORY = 20002
VIX_E_NO_SUCH_PROCESS = 20003
VIX_E_FILE_NAME_TOO_LONG = 20004
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_NO_IMAGE = 21000
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_IMAGE_INACCESIBLE = 21001
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_NO_DEVICE = 21002
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED = 21003
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_CANCELLED = 21004
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_INIT_FAILED = 21005
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_AUTO_NOT_SUPPORTED = 21006
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_GUEST_NOT_READY = 21007
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_SIG_CHECK_FAILED = 21008
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_ERROR = 21009
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_ALREADY_UP_TO_DATE = 21010
VIX_E_TOOLS_INSTALL_IN_PROGRESS = 21011
VIX_E_WRAPPER_WORKSTATION_NOT_INSTALLED = 22001
VIX_E_WRAPPER_VERSION_NOT_FOUND = 22002
VIX_E_WRAPPER_SERVICEPROVIDER_NOT_FOUND = 22003
VIX_E_WRAPPER_PLAYER_NOT_INSTALLED = 22004
VIX_E_WRAPPER_RUNTIME_NOT_INSTALLED = 22005
VIX_E_WRAPPER_MULTIPLE_SERVICEPROVIDERS = 22006
VIX_E_MNTAPI_MOUNTPT_NOT_FOUND = 24000
VIX_E_MNTAPI_MOUNTPT_IN_USE = 24001
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DISK_NOT_FOUND = 24002
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DISK_NOT_MOUNTED = 24003
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DISK_IS_MOUNTED = 24004
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DISK_NOT_SAFE = 24005
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DISK_CANT_OPEN = 24006
VIX_E_MNTAPI_CANT_READ_PARTS = 24007
VIX_E_MNTAPI_UMOUNT_APP_NOT_FOUND = 24008
VIX_E_MNTAPI_UMOUNT = 24009
VIX_E_MNTAPI_NO_MOUNTABLE_PARTITONS = 24010
VIX_E_MNTAPI_PARTITION_RANGE = 24011
VIX_E_MNTAPI_PERM = 24012
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DICT = 24013
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DICT_LOCKED = 24014
VIX_E_MNTAPI_OPEN_HANDLES = 24015
VIX_E_MNTAPI_CANT_MAKE_VAR_DIR = 24016
VIX_E_MNTAPI_NO_ROOT = 24017
VIX_E_MNTAPI_LOOP_FAILED = 24018
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DAEMON = 24019
VIX_E_MNTAPI_INTERNAL = 24020
VIX_E_MNTAPI_SYSTEM = 24021
VIX_E_MNTAPI_NO_CONNECTION_DETAILS = 24022
VIX_E_MNTAPI_INCOMPATIBLE_VERSION = 24300
VIX_E_MNTAPI_OS_ERROR = 24301
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DRIVE_LETTER_IN_USE = 24302
VIX_E_MNTAPI_DRIVE_LETTER_ALREADY_ASSIGNED = 24303
VIX_E_MNTAPI_VOLUME_NOT_MOUNTED = 24304
VIX_E_MNTAPI_VOLUME_ALREADY_MOUNTED = 24305
VIX_E_MNTAPI_FORMAT_FAILURE = 24306
VIX_E_MNTAPI_NO_DRIVER = 24307
VIX_E_MNTAPI_ALREADY_OPENED = 24308
VIX_E_MNTAPI_ITEM_NOT_FOUND = 24309
VIX_E_MNTAPI_UNSUPPROTED_BOOT_LOADER = 24310
VIX_E_MNTAPI_UNSUPPROTED_OS = 24311
VIX_E_MNTAPI_CODECONVERSION = 24312
VIX_E_MNTAPI_REGWRITE_ERROR = 24313
VIX_E_MNTAPI_UNSUPPORTED_FT_VOLUME = 24314
VIX_E_MNTAPI_PARTITION_NOT_FOUND = 24315
VIX_E_MNTAPI_PUTFILE_ERROR = 24316
VIX_E_MNTAPI_GETFILE_ERROR = 24317
VIX_E_MNTAPI_REG_NOT_OPENED = 24318
VIX_E_MNTAPI_REGDELKEY_ERROR = 24319
VIX_E_MNTAPI_CREATE_PARTITIONTABLE_ERROR = 24320
VIX_E_MNTAPI_OPEN_FAILURE = 24321
VIX_E_MNTAPI_VOLUME_NOT_WRITABLE = 24322
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL = 30001
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_URL_MALFORMAT = 30003
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_COULDNT_RESOLVE_PROXY = 30005
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST = 30006
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_COULDNT_CONNECT = 30007
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR = 30022
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT = 30028
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR = 30035
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS = 30047
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_TRANSFER = 30200
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_SSL_SECURITY = 30201
VIX_E_NET_HTTP_GENERIC = 30202
VIX_PROPERTYTYPE_ANY = 0
VIX_PROPERTYTYPE_INTEGER = 1
VIX_PROPERTYTYPE_STRING = 2
VIX_PROPERTYTYPE_BOOL = 3
VIX_PROPERTYTYPE_HANDLE = 4
VIX_PROPERTYTYPE_INT64 = 5
VIX_PROPERTYTYPE_BLOB = 6
VIX_PROPERTY_NONE = 0
VIX_PROPERTY_META_DATA_CONTAINER = 2
VIX_PROPERTY_HOST_HOSTTYPE = 50
VIX_PROPERTY_HOST_API_VERSION = 51
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_NUM_VCPUS = 101
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_VMX_PATHNAME = 103
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_VMTEAM_PATHNAME = 105
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_MEMORY_SIZE = 106
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_READ_ONLY = 107
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_NAME = 108
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_GUESTOS = 109
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_IN_VMTEAM = 128
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_POWER_STATE = 129
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_TOOLS_STATE = 152
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_IS_RUNNING = 196
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_SUPPORTED_FEATURES = 197
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_IS_RECORDING = 236
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_IS_REPLAYING = 237
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_ERROR_CODE = 3000
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_VM_IN_GROUP = 3001
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_USER_MESSAGE = 3002
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_EXIT_CODE = 3004
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_COMMAND_OUTPUT = 3005
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_HANDLE = 3010
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_GUEST_OBJECT_EXISTS = 3011
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_GUEST_PROGRAM_ELAPSED_TIME = 3017
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_GUEST_PROGRAM_EXIT_CODE = 3018
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_ITEM_NAME = 3035
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_FOUND_ITEM_DESCRIPTION = 3036
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_SHARED_FOLDER_COUNT = 3046
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_SHARED_FOLDER_HOST = 3048
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_SHARED_FOLDER_FLAGS = 3049
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_PROCESS_ID = 3051
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_PROCESS_OWNER = 3052
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_PROCESS_COMMAND = 3053
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_FILE_FLAGS = 3054
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_PROCESS_START_TIME = 3055
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_VM_VARIABLE_STRING = 3056
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_PROCESS_BEING_DEBUGGED = 3057
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_SCREEN_IMAGE_SIZE = 3058
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_SCREEN_IMAGE_DATA = 3059
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_FILE_SIZE = 3061
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_FILE_MOD_TIME = 3062
VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_EXTRA_ERROR_INFO = 3084
VIX_PROPERTY_FOUND_ITEM_LOCATION = 4010
VIX_PROPERTY_SNAPSHOT_DISPLAYNAME = 4200
VIX_PROPERTY_SNAPSHOT_DESCRIPTION = 4201
VIX_PROPERTY_SNAPSHOT_POWERSTATE = 4205
VIX_PROPERTY_SNAPSHOT_IS_REPLAYABLE = 4207
VIX_PROPERTY_GUEST_SHAREDFOLDERS_SHARES_PATH = 4525
VIX_PROPERTY_VM_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD = 7001
VIX_EVENTTYPE_JOB_COMPLETED = 2
VIX_EVENTTYPE_JOB_PROGRESS = 3
VIX_EVENTTYPE_FIND_ITEM = 8
VIX_EVENTTYPE_CALLBACK_SIGNALLED = 2
VIX_FILE_ATTRIBUTES_DIRECTORY = 0x0001
VIX_FILE_ATTRIBUTES_SYMLINK = 0x0002
VIX_HOSTOPTION_USE_EVENT_PUMP = 0x0008
VIX_SERVICEPROVIDER_DEFAULT = 1
VIX_SERVICEPROVIDER_VMWARE_SERVER = 2
VIX_SERVICEPROVIDER_VMWARE_WORKSTATION = 3
VIX_SERVICEPROVIDER_VMWARE_PLAYER = 4
VIX_SERVICEPROVIDER_VMWARE_VI_SERVER = 10
VIX_API_VERSION = -1
VIX_FIND_RUNNING_VMS = 1
VIX_FIND_REGISTERED_VMS = 4
VIX_VMOPEN_NORMAL = 0x0
VIX_PUMPEVENTOPTION_NONE = 0
VIX_VMPOWEROP_NORMAL = 0
VIX_VMPOWEROP_FROM_GUEST = 0x0004
VIX_VMPOWEROP_SUPPRESS_SNAPSHOT_POWERON = 0x0080
VIX_VMPOWEROP_LAUNCH_GUI = 0x0200
VIX_VMPOWEROP_START_VM_PAUSED = 0x1000
VIX_VMDELETE_DISK_FILES = 0x0002
VIX_POWERSTATE_POWERING_OFF = 0x0001
VIX_POWERSTATE_POWERED_OFF = 0x0002
VIX_POWERSTATE_POWERING_ON = 0x0004
VIX_POWERSTATE_POWERED_ON = 0x0008
VIX_POWERSTATE_SUSPENDING = 0x0010
VIX_POWERSTATE_SUSPENDED = 0x0020
VIX_POWERSTATE_TOOLS_RUNNING = 0x0040
VIX_POWERSTATE_RESETTING = 0x0080
VIX_POWERSTATE_BLOCKED_ON_MSG = 0x0100
VIX_POWERSTATE_PAUSED = 0x0200
VIX_POWERSTATE_RESUMING = 0x0800
VIX_TOOLSSTATE_UNKNOWN = 0x0001
VIX_TOOLSSTATE_RUNNING = 0x0002
VIX_TOOLSSTATE_NOT_INSTALLED = 0x0004
VIX_VM_SUPPORT_SHARED_FOLDERS = 0x0001
VIX_VM_SUPPORT_MULTIPLE_SNAPSHOTS = 0x0002
VIX_VM_SUPPORT_TOOLS_INSTALL = 0x0004
VIX_VM_SUPPORT_HARDWARE_UPGRADE = 0x0008
VIX_LOGIN_IN_GUEST_REQUIRE_INTERACTIVE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x08
VIX_RUNPROGRAM_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY = 0x0001
VIX_RUNPROGRAM_ACTIVATE_WINDOW = 0x0002
VIX_VM_GUEST_VARIABLE = 1
VIX_VM_CONFIG_RUNTIME_ONLY = 2
VIX_GUEST_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = 3
VIX_SNAPSHOT_REMOVE_CHILDREN = 0x0001
VIX_SNAPSHOT_INCLUDE_MEMORY = 0x0002
VIX_SHAREDFOLDER_WRITE_ACCESS = 0x04
VIX_CAPTURESCREENFORMAT_PNG = 0x01
VIX_CAPTURESCREENFORMAT_PNG_NOCOMPRESS = 0x02
VIX_CLONETYPE_FULL = 0
VIX_CLONETYPE_LINKED = 1
VIX_INSTALLTOOLS_MOUNT_TOOLS_INSTALLER = 0x00
VIX_INSTALLTOOLS_AUTO_UPGRADE = 0x01
VIX_INSTALLTOOLS_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY = 0x02

# functions
vix.Vix_GetErrorText.restype = c_char_p
vix.Vix_GetErrorText.argtypes = [VixError,c_char_p]
vix.Vix_ReleaseHandle.restype = None
vix.Vix_ReleaseHandle.argtypes = [VixHandle]
vix.Vix_AddRefHandle.restype = None
vix.Vix_AddRefHandle.argtypes = [VixHandle]
vix.Vix_GetHandleType.restype = VixHandleType
vix.Vix_GetHandleType.argtypes = [VixHandle]
vix.Vix_GetProperties.restype = VixError
# warning - vix.Vix_GetProperties takes variable argument list
vix.Vix_GetProperties.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixPropertyID]
vix.Vix_GetPropertyType.restype = VixError
vix.Vix_GetPropertyType.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixPropertyID,POINTER(VixPropertyType)]
vix.Vix_FreeBuffer.restype = None
vix.Vix_FreeBuffer.argtypes = [c_void_p]
vix.VixHost_Connect.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixHost_Connect.argtypes = [c_int,VixServiceProvider,c_char_p,c_int,c_char_p,c_char_p,VixHostOptions,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixHost_Disconnect.restype = None
vix.VixHost_Disconnect.argtypes = [VixHandle]
vix.VixHost_RegisterVM.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixHost_RegisterVM.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixHost_UnregisterVM.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixHost_UnregisterVM.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixHost_FindItems.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixHost_FindItems.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixFindItemType,VixHandle,c_int32,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixHost_OpenVM.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixHost_OpenVM.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,VixVMOpenOptions,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.Vix_PumpEvents.restype = None
vix.Vix_PumpEvents.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixPumpEventsOptions]
vix.VixPropertyList_AllocPropertyList.restype = VixError
# warning - vix.VixPropertyList_AllocPropertyList takes variable argument list
vix.VixPropertyList_AllocPropertyList.argtypes = [VixHandle,POINTER(VixHandle),c_int]
vix.VixVM_Open.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_Open.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_PowerOn.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_PowerOn.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixVMPowerOpOptions,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_PowerOff.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_PowerOff.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixVMPowerOpOptions,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_Reset.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_Reset.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixVMPowerOpOptions,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_Suspend.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_Suspend.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixVMPowerOpOptions,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_Pause.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_Pause.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_Unpause.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_Unpause.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_Delete.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_Delete.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixVMDeleteOptions,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_BeginRecording.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_BeginRecording.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_EndRecording.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_EndRecording.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_BeginReplay.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_BeginReplay.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixHandle,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_EndReplay.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_EndReplay.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_WaitForToolsInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_WaitForToolsInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_LoginInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_LoginInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_LogoutFromGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_LogoutFromGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_RunProgramInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_RunProgramInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,VixRunProgramOptions,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_ListProcessesInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_ListProcessesInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_KillProcessInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_KillProcessInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_uint64,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_RunScriptInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_RunScriptInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,VixRunProgramOptions,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_OpenUrlInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_OpenUrlInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_CopyFileFromHostToGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_CopyFileFromHostToGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_CopyFileFromGuestToHost.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_CopyFileFromGuestToHost.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_DeleteFileInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_DeleteFileInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_FileExistsInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_FileExistsInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_RenameFileInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_RenameFileInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_CreateTempFileInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_CreateTempFileInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_GetFileInfoInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_GetFileInfoInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_ListDirectoryInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_ListDirectoryInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_CreateDirectoryInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_CreateDirectoryInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_DeleteDirectoryInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_DeleteDirectoryInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_DirectoryExistsInGuest.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_DirectoryExistsInGuest.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_ReadVariable.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_ReadVariable.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,c_char_p,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_WriteVariable.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_WriteVariable.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_GetNumRootSnapshots.restype = VixError
vix.VixVM_GetNumRootSnapshots.argtypes = [VixHandle,POINTER(c_int)]
vix.VixVM_GetRootSnapshot.restype = VixError
vix.VixVM_GetRootSnapshot.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,POINTER(VixHandle)]
vix.VixVM_GetCurrentSnapshot.restype = VixError
vix.VixVM_GetCurrentSnapshot.argtypes = [VixHandle,POINTER(VixHandle)]
vix.VixVM_GetNamedSnapshot.restype = VixError
vix.VixVM_GetNamedSnapshot.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixHandle)]
vix.VixVM_RemoveSnapshot.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_RemoveSnapshot.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixHandle,VixRemoveSnapshotOptions,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_RevertToSnapshot.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_RevertToSnapshot.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixHandle,VixVMPowerOpOptions,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_CreateSnapshot.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_CreateSnapshot.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,VixCreateSnapshotOptions,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_EnableSharedFolders.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_EnableSharedFolders.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_byte,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_GetNumSharedFolders.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_GetNumSharedFolders.argtypes = [VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_GetSharedFolderState.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_GetSharedFolderState.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_SetSharedFolderState.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_SetSharedFolderState.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,VixMsgSharedFolderOptions,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_AddSharedFolder.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_AddSharedFolder.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_char_p,VixMsgSharedFolderOptions,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_RemoveSharedFolder.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_RemoveSharedFolder.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_CaptureScreenImage.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_CaptureScreenImage.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_Clone.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_Clone.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixHandle,VixCloneType,c_char_p,c_int,VixHandle,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_UpgradeVirtualHardware.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_UpgradeVirtualHardware.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixVM_InstallTools.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_InstallTools.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
vix.VixJob_Wait.restype = VixError
# warning - vix.VixJob_Wait takes variable argument list
vix.VixJob_Wait.argtypes = [VixHandle,VixPropertyID]
vix.VixJob_CheckCompletion.restype = VixError
vix.VixJob_CheckCompletion.argtypes = [VixHandle,POINTER(c_byte)]
vix.VixJob_GetError.restype = VixError
vix.VixJob_GetError.argtypes = [VixHandle]
vix.VixJob_GetNumProperties.restype = c_int
vix.VixJob_GetNumProperties.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int]
vix.VixJob_GetNthProperties.restype = VixError
# warning - vix.VixJob_GetNthProperties takes variable argument list
vix.VixJob_GetNthProperties.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,c_int]
vix.VixSnapshot_GetNumChildren.restype = VixError
vix.VixSnapshot_GetNumChildren.argtypes = [VixHandle,POINTER(c_int)]
vix.VixSnapshot_GetChild.restype = VixError
vix.VixSnapshot_GetChild.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_int,POINTER(VixHandle)]
vix.VixSnapshot_GetParent.restype = VixError
vix.VixSnapshot_GetParent.argtypes = [VixHandle,POINTER(VixHandle)]
```

Comment: for example:                                                                 vix_ok = 0

Comment: Probably would be nicer to use the symbolic names in your code, rather than the magic numbers.  This is not strictly required to call the methods, though.

Comment: ok thanks, I try now to do this and I will write you to say the result Thank you very much!!

Comment: jeje ok you are right I will search a woman for you!!it´s a joke... I have a problem: I copy to a module called VixLib.py and import it from another module. It returns this error: Atribute error: funtion 'vix_addRefHandle' not found...

Comment: I got this too, the VIX API kit contains a number of different configurations.  The vix.dll that I found in `VMware VIX\Workstation-7.1.0\32bit` directory would import successfully using this Python code.  (I also updated my C->ctypes utility to read the enum constants, will edit my answer to include them.)

Comment: oh thanks I was using elder version of API and it hasn´t all functions!!

Comment: I have another problem: I try to connect and received this error:

Comment: "Don´t found  the ordinal 3283 in LIBEAY32.dll" what´s happends??

Comment: We are still working out the right version of VIX for you to use. I have been using this utility (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) to view the names and ordinals exported in each DLL.  Ordinal 3283 is in the LIBEAY32.dll found in `VMware VIX\Workstate-7.0.0\32bit`.  I don't know why they ship so many different binaries, but just the one .h file.  Try those binaries.

Comment: ... and I'd appreciate if you'd click on the check mark for this answer, since it seems to be the most direct solution to your question.

Comment: yes your answer is the best but I´m new in this forum and I don´t have idea about mark answers, etc... I do it now, sorry

Comment: the problem with libeay32.dll was that I have an older version of libeay32 that make the error...

Comment: I try this: err = VixLib.vix.VixJob_Wait(jobHandle,
                                   VixLib.VIX_PROPERTY_JOB_RESULT_HANDLE,
                                   byref(hostHandle),
                                   VixLib.VIX_PROPERTY_NONE)         but it returns error.. how can I use this funtion?

Comment: I don´t say nothing, I just do it thanks for all, I´m your biggest fan!!

Answer (score 2):

The [original tutorial](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html) is quite good.   You are going to need to be more specific about what you don't understand.

As a quick start:

```
import ctypes

PATH_DLL = "C:/path/to/vmware/dll.dll"
dllLib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(PATH_DLL)
someFunc = dllLib.funcExportedFromDLL ## what c function are you trying to use
someFunc.restype = ctypes.c_long ## tell ctypes the expected return type of the C function
returnValue = someFunc(ctypes.c_int(1), ctypes.c_double(1.0)) ## call the c function with ctypes converted args
...etc..
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is that I have some .dll and .lib and I don´t know which are the necessary...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a extension module using [Cython](http://cython.org).
It is a lot easier than using ctypes, and the results are way better. At least it segfaults less frequently.

Comment: That's no fun nosklo, ctypes is so frustratingly awesome!

Comment: I have installed cython but I don´t know how to do this...  I never have program... I need some code samples for learn...

Comment: Why do you so-say?  I find ctypes to be far easier, doubly so on the distribution end, where all you need to deliver is Python code.

Comment: @llasram: You clearly haven't worked with both solutions to say that.

Comment: @igferne: There is a tutorial on the link I provided.

Comment: @nosklo: I've actually used both pretty extensively.  In Pyrex I've written a wrapper for a large VMware API (coincidentally), wrappers for several small libraries, and some stand-alone modules.  With ctypes I've wrapped some big chunks of the Windows debugging APIs, chunks of OpenSSL, most of libpcap, and tons of small libraries.  I've found ctypes code to be easier to write and far easier to distribute.  Bonus: one day ctypes code will work in Jython and other Python implementations too.