# Vix API in python

Tags: python, vix

I need to import VIX api libs in ubuntu using ctypes module.
When I do:

```
 vix = CDLL('libvix.so')
```

It fails: "cannot open..."

what´s the problem??? libvix.so and python module are in the same directory

thanks!!

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but may give you some other help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687762/use-of-ctypes-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rest of the error is something like

```
OSError: libvix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then you probably need to put the location of the libvix.so in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

Comment: Oh yes!! jajaja the rest of my messagge error is this! I try to do this and say you!